# missing custom labels of Prometheus in PagerDuty alerts

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, prometheus, monitoring, pagerduty

I have a Prometheus alert rule for CPU utilisation for my pods set like below for apps in a specific namespace and if it cross 90% percentage trigger an alert(removed some details specific but yes its almost like below) and its triggering the PagerDuty alert.

```
- alert: CpuUtilizationWarning
  expr:  avg by (kubernetes_io_zone) (rate( container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{ pod=~"app.*", container="app", namespace="app"}[5m] )) / on() group_left() avg( kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores{ pod=~"app.*", container="app", namespace="apps } ) * 100 > 90
  for: 5m
  labels:
    severity: warning
    service: location
    product: backend-app
  annotations:
    description: 'CPU utilization of {{ $labels.product }} pod is exceeding {{ $labels.severity }} and value is {{ $value }} %'
    summary: '{{ $labels.severity }} CPU utilization of {{ $labels.product } pod
```

and alerts are coming like below in PD, sharing the sample alerts description that got triggered in PD.

```
Labels:
 - alertname = CpuUtilizationWarning
 - monitor = prometheus
 - product = backend-app
 - service = location
 - severity = warning
 - kubernetes_io_zone = us-east-1c
Annotations:
 - description = CPU utilization of pod is exceeding and value is 95.099865567118 %
 - summary =  CPU utilization of pod
```

But as you can see from the above PD annotation of `description` and `summary` the custom labels `{{ $labels.product }}` and `{{ $labels.severity }}` is not interpolating the values in description and summary part in PD alert that got triggered.

It should be like below in PD:

```
Annotations:
 - description = CPU utilization of backend-app pod is exceeding warning and value is 95.099865567118 %
 - summary =  waring CPU utilization of backend-app pod
```

That is it should add `backend-app` in place of {{ $labels.product }} and `warning` in place of {{ $labels.severity }}.
I've checked the logs, alertmanager, and alerts tab couldnt find any issues on why label values are not getting picked up.
Any suggestions on why PD is not picking up custom labels.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with PagerDuty. You custom labels are introduced at the same step as annotations are created. As a result, those labels are not yet accessible to be used in description as labels.

Comment: Since labels are known at configuration, why don't you simply write `summary: warning CPU...`?

Comment: thanks @markalex unfortunately I  cannot hardcode eventhough the values are known coz, we have around 30-40+ product labels based on each team, 'backend-app' is one such and the whole purpose of making it interpolate the value is coz so that it can be made like a self serve platform for our developers and we also use Chef for deploying this so devs can just copy paste and make the changes as per their need